# How to implement reactive variable as a template argument

Tags: meteor

I would like to use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) with Meteor. It is a fancy textarea for editing the code.

I used [perak package](https://github.com/perak/codemirror), which is nice. I can get back edited content easily, but I can't update it.

Ideally:

- I would like to be able update it reactively if it's not focused. Same way as <input> works.
- I still want to save the content on input. I can do it now easily, but want to keep that ability.

The problem is that arguments to template does not seem to be a reactive data source. E.g.:

```
{{> CodeMirror id="some-id" name="someName" options=editorOptions code=editorCode}}
```

reactivity in `code` is lost.

My best idea how to fix is to pass `Session` variable name [PR](https://github.com/perak/codemirror/pull/2/files):

```
if (this.data.reactiveVar) {
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    if (!editor.hasFocus()) {
      editor.setValue(Session.get(this.data.reactiveVar));
    }
  });
}
```

Is there a better way of doing that? So we can use any reactive source, not just session variables.

Comment: can you pass a template instance that is a "parent view" to the newly created template?

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand.